# Ruby on Rails Dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dragonfly-gem

I have the following Model which has an accessor that receives an audio file with WAV format and then stores it

```
class Audio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contribution
  belongs_to :recorder


  dragonfly_accessor  :audio, :app_name => :videos do
    storage_options do |audio|
      { path: "audios/#{audio.name}" }
    end
  end


end
```

What I want to do is to convert this audio from WAV to MP3 before saving it.

Comment: What did you find when you searched about converting files from WAV to MP3 using Ruby? What have you tried? Please read "[mcve]".

Comment: I started a sample app for this https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample_convert_mp3_to_wav I stuck when I am doing wav.to_mp3 but I will keep working at this

Comment: Did you try the solution suggested by @ddgd ? Looks like that should work

Comment: how about using a gem https://github.com/pacso/paperclip-wav-mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dragonfly cannot do it by default, you need to add [a custom processor](https://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/processors/) and probably use some command line tool for it, [here's a few examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216445/converting-wav-files-to-high-quality-mp3-using-linux-terminal)

So if you go with one of the top responses from that thread and use libav-tools your custom processor will look something like this (you might also need to change new_path file extension to .mp_3):

```
processor :to_mp3 do |content|
  content.shell_update do |old_path, new_path|
    "avconv -i #{old_path} #{new_path}"
  end
end
```